# How to delete double quotes in fetched data

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to delete the double quotes you can see in this example, I don't know if this was efficient way to fetch data and render in to DOM but if you know how to do this fetching proper way please help me.

```js
async function getJson() {
  const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data.results);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('authors').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data.results[i].name.first + " " + data.results[i].name.last);
  }
}

getJson();
```

```html
<p id="authors"></p>
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify` in the first place? What are you actually trying to do and I'll update my answer with more detail.

Comment: you are right I'm just a newbie :)

Comment: Don't worry about that - we all learned once!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing doesnt make sense. You're using `JSON.stringify` around just a firstName + {space} + lastName. Just dont do that and you wont get the quotes.

```js
async function getJson(){
    const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
    const data = await response.json(); 
    
    console.log(data.results);
    for(let i=0;i<data.results.length;i++){
        document.getElementById('authors').innerHTML += data.results[i].name.first  + " "  + data.results[i].name.last ;
    }


}


getJson();
```

```html
<p id="authors"></p>
```